# PHP Looping to array into multipe cols

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried to find a solution for this but am stumped.

I have an array with the following structure:

```
S1 1 Fred
S1 2 NULL
S1 3 Mary
S2 1 Jim
S2 2 Mary
S2 3 NULL
S3 1 NULL
S3 2 Fred
S3 3 NULL
```

and what I want is to output html table with the following stucture

```
    S1      S2     S3
1   Fred     Jim      NULL
2   NULL     Mary     Fred
3   Mary     NULL     NULL
```

This array is built from 3 or more tables (s1 s2 s3 ...Sx) Tables can be added as required and the new table will have all rows and fields set to NULL, each table has equal number of rows.

I've tried a number of different loops etc but can not solve it.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Add a `var_dump` of your array please

Comment: OH OK, I certainly dont want any one to do all the work :( But I have tried a couple of different nested foreach loops (please note that the above structure is just an example and not real data).

Comment: Welcome to SO! Posting clearly what you have, what you want, and what you have tried _in your question_ will help us help you. The structure of your original array is unclear. What are keys, and what are values? Please clarify, perhaps with a `var_dump` as @Machavity requested.

Comment: Are you sure that there will always be one entry on the third column for each pair of values from first and second ?

Comment: Hi Thanks all for your comments. Clearly I haven't expressed myself well and need to go back and reconstruct my question. This is the reason I don't post questions because 99% of the time I can find the answer to my problem from other posts.